# image doesnt upload using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

Ok so in my app I am trying to allow image uploading using multer.  My app is built using node.js and my database is using mongodb.  When I create an account and select an image for the avatar image, it creates the account but automatically uses the no-image.png file I have setup in case someone doesn't select an image.  Here is the code... Any help will be awesome.

```
    // handle signup logic
    router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err){
          req.flash("error", err.message);
          return res.redirect("/register");
        }
        var newUser = new User({
          username: req.body.username,
          firstName: req.body.firstName,
          lastName: req.body.lastName,
          email: req.body.email,
          bio: req.body.bio
        });

        if(typeof req.file !== "undefined") {
          newUser.avatar = '/uploads/userImg/' + req.file.filename;
        } else {
          newUser.avatar = '/uploads/userImg/no-image.png';
        }
        console.log(newUser);
        if(req.body.adminCode === process.env.ADMINCODE) {
          newUser.isAdmin = true;
        }

        if(req.body.answer !== process.env.SECRET){
          req.flash("error", "answer the question");
          return res.redirect("back");
        } else {
          User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
            if(err){
              return res.render("register", {error: err.message});
            }
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
              req.flash("success", "Welcome to Let's Camp " + user.username);
              res.redirect("/campgrounds"); 
            }); 
          });
        }
      });
    });



    var multer = require("multer");
    var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/uploads/userImg');
       },
      filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
      }
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('image');



<% include ./partials/header %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
          <form action="/register" method="post">
            <h1 class="text-center">Sign Up</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
              <input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
              <input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="avatar">Avatar Image URL</label>
              <input id="avatar" class="form-control" type="file" name="avatar">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="bio">Bio</label>
              <textarea id="bio" class="form-control" type="bio" name="bio" rows="5" placeholder="Write a short description of yourself and what you enjoy about camping."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="adminCode">Admin Code</label>
              <input id="adminCode" class="form-control" type="text" name="adminCode" placeholder="Admin Code">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-0">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="number">Enter: I Love Camping</label>
              <input id="number" class="form-control" type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Answer*" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up!</button>
            </div>
            <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p class="text-center"><strong>*</strong> indicates a required field.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% include ./partials/footer %>
```

If I use enctype="multipart/form-data" I get an error for some reason but if I leave it off it completes but the image still doesnt upload.  Just reverts to the no-image.png

Comment: can You add to Your question how You defined `upload` method?

Comment: I just did... I just attached it to the bottom of the original post ... Thanks

Comment: @DarrellPawson the code is correct, need to check frontend. How You send the file? simple form with enctype=multipart/form-data ? or over ajax?

Comment: also check if path exists (multer does not create folders I guess) and use correct path: `path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'uploads', 'userImg')` or `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'uploads', 'userImg')` - if router file is in folder

Comment: i added the form code at the bottom, and the path does exist... I just uses the else statement vs using the image selected

Comment: if I add enctype="multipart/form-data" I get a flash message that says unexpected field... I am trying to debug that one still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to post file You've to use `entype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form action="/register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If You've other problems so fix that problem.

from [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname) :

> .single(fieldname)
>
> Accept a single file with the name fieldname. The single file will be stored in req.file.

So create upload method like this and call it in Your router:

```
var uploadAvatar = multer({ storage : storage}).single('avatar');
```

or rename Your input file `name="image"` :

```
<input id="avatar" class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
```

Comment: dude, I figured it out.  Ok so when I am defining upload the .single('image') was what was messed up.  On the html form it was labeled as avatar so when I add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag I was getting an unexpected field.  when I changed it to .single('avatar') it works.

Comment: I have been messing with this for 3 days now... Thanks for the help

Comment: @DarrellPawson that was I writing just now :D

Comment: lol @num8er ... now my next project on this app is gonna be adding google captcha onto this app vs having to type a predefined text string on the register form.  im using c9 to build the app so if you wanna look at the code ill send you the link...

Comment: it's 03:25 AM, I'm going to sleep :P

Comment: @DarrellPawson use: `express-recaptcha` package, it's done like a middleware to ease life or read this tutorial: https://stackfame.com/google-recaptcha-node-express

Comment: I am working on it ... check out my post here please  @num8er https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744487/google-recaptcha-nodejs-app