# google recaptcha nodejs app

Tags: node.js, recaptcha

Ok so I am trying to implement Google Recaptcha into my register page for my app.  Everything on the front end seems to work as far as it loads the page and when I click "I am not a robot" it asks me to verify images and then... when I click submit, It tells me to "Please select captcha" and it redirects me back to the register page. Thats how I have the code setup if someone doesn't select the captcha checkmark but I cannot figure out why it won't continue and create the user.  Here is the code...

```
// handle signup logic
router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.captcha === undefined || req.body.captcha === "" || req.body.captcha === null){
      req.flash("error", "Please select captcha");
      return res.redirect("/register");
    }
    // secret key
    var secretKey = process.env.CAPTCHA;
    // Verify URL
    var verifyURL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${req.body.captcha}&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;
    // Make request to Verify URL
    request(verifyURL, (err, response, body) => {
      // if not successful
      if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){
        req.flash("error", "Captcha Failed");
        return res.redirect("/register");
      }

      // if successful
      upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if(err){
          console.log(err.message);
          req.flash("error", err.message);
          return res.redirect("/register");
       }
       var newUser = new User({
         username: req.body.username,
         firstName: req.body.firstName,
         lastName: req.body.lastName,
         email: req.body.email,
         bio: req.body.bio
       });

       if(typeof req.file !== "undefined") {
         newUser.avatar = '/uploads/userImg/' + req.file.filename;
       } else {
         newUser.avatar = '/uploads/userImg/no-image.png';
       }
       console.log(newUser);
       if(req.body.adminCode === process.env.ADMINCODE) {
         newUser.isAdmin = true;
      }

      if(req.body.answer !== process.env.SECRET){
        req.flash("error", "answer the question");
        return res.redirect("back");
      } else {
        User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
          if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            return res.render("register", {error: err.message});
          }
          passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            req.flash("success", "Welcome to Let's Camp " + user.username);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds"); 
          }); 
        });
      }
    });
  });

 });

<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <form id="register" action="/register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1 class="text-center">Sign Up</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input id="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input id="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="avatar">Avatar Image URL</label>
          <input id="avatar" class="form-control" type="file" name="avatar">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="bio">Bio</label>
          <textarea id="bio" class="form-control" type="bio" name="bio" rows="5" placeholder="Write a short description of yourself and what you enjoy about camping."></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adminCode">Admin Code</label>
          <input id="adminCode" class="form-control" type="text" name="adminCode" placeholder="Admin Code">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="number">Enter: Answer</label>
          <input id="number" class="form-control" type="text" id="answer" name="answer" placeholder="Answer*" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="g-recaptcha form-group" data-sitekey="6LduxzsUAAAAAAoten8FA_zg12PjA3QfSjF5vFvY"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up!</button>
        </div>
        <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <p class="text-center"><strong>*</strong> indicates a required field.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Comment: Add html to answer.

Comment: @num8er, I added it to the bottom. Thanks

Comment: I have the <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> located in my header.ejs file

Comment: in Your html I no `captcha` field, so it's been generated by js code from google. By many tutorials I see that captcha data stored in: `req.body['g-recaptcha-response']`

Comment: so where would I add the captcha field? or use req.body['g-recaptcha-response' ?  I'm only asking cause I'm basing this off a few tutorials plus what I am seeing on googles site and this is as far as I've come

Comment: No need to add field in Your html, google's js code will add it itself. Just handle it in Your nodejs code. Read my answer.

Comment: What you are getting after doing `console.log(req.body)` inside `router.post('/register')` ?

Comment: I got it fixed, thanks.  It had to do with multer not wanting to play with google captcha

Answer (score 1):

It's not `req.body.captcha`

Seems like You've not read tutorial correctly.

From [this tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2016/03/google-recaptcha-node-js-tutorial/) is see such example:

```
app.post('/submit',function(req,res){
  // g-recaptcha-response is the key that browser will generate upon form submit.
  // if its blank or null means user has not selected the captcha, so return the error.
  if(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === undefined || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === '' || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === null) {
    // not passed validation
  }
```

And from [this file](https://github.com/pdupavillon/express-recaptcha/blob/master/lib/express-recaptcha.js#L52) is see such code at line `52` :

```
if(req.body && req.body['g-recaptcha-response']) response = req.body['g-recaptcha-response'];
```

Both of them proves that "invisible" field is accessible under `req.body['g-recaptcha-response']`

HERE IS THE FIX:

this:

```
const captcha = req.body['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!captcha){
  req.flash("error", "Please select captcha");
  return res.redirect("/register");
}
```

and this:

```
// Verify URL
var verifyURL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${captcha}&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;
```

or just create simple middleware `catchReCaptcha` and attach to router:

```
// middleware that catches g-recaptcha-response and puts in req.body.captcha
const catchReCaptcha = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body && req.body['g-recaptcha-response']) {
    req.body.captcha = req.body['g-recaptcha-response'];
  }
  next();
};

// attached middleware to register route
router.post("/register", catchReCaptcha, (req, res) => {
```

but keep in mind You'll have conflicts of parsing `multipart/form-data` since `upload` method responsible also for parsing body of request for that content-type.

Comment: Even with that fix, It still tells me to select the captcha and starts the form all over again...

Comment: which fix example You've used?

Comment: @DarrellPawson can You do `console.log(req.body)` right under `router.post` line and try to pass it again, then copy output of console where will be that log and put here in comments?

Comment: {} thats all I get

Comment: the first two that you sent ... I havent done the middleware

Comment: https://ide.c9.io/dpawson905/webdevbootcamp   and the directory is YelpCamp/routes/index.js ... if that will help any at all